# CTDB Samba failover not highly available

Tags: cluster-computing, samba, failover, smb, ceph

**My Setup**

3 nodes running ceph + cephfs
2 of these nodes running CTDB & Samba
1 client (not one of the 3 servers)

It is a Lab setup, so only one nic per server=node, one subnet as well as all Ceph components plus Samba on the same servers. I'm aware, that this is not the way to go.

**The problem**

I want to host a clustered Samba file share on top of Ceph with ctdb. I followed the CTDB documentation (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/CTDB_and_Clustered_Samba#Configuring_Clusters_with_CTDB) and parts of this: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_CTDB_GPFS_Cluster_HowTo.
The cluster is running and a share is reachable, readable and writeable on both nodes, my smb.conf looks as follows:

```
[global]
netbios name = CEPHFS
workgroup = SIMPLE
clustering = yes
idmap config * : backend = autorid
idmap config * : range = 1000000-1999999
log file = /var/log/samba/smb.log

# Set files creation permissions
create mask = 664
force create mode = 664

# Set directory creation mask
directory mask = 2775
force directory mode = 2775

[public]
comment = public share
path = /mnt/mycephfs/testshare
public = yes
writeable = yes
only guest = yes
ea support = yes
```

CTDB manages Samba and reports both nodes as OK.

But when i read or write to one of the nodes via the public IP and let it fail (restarting ctdb), the read or write fails. A second write attempt succeeds (the public IP gets taken by the other host successfully).

But CTDB should be able to do this according to https://ctdb.samba.org/ -> IP Takeover?
I have a tcpdump of the new server (the one taking over the public ip) sending a tcp RST to my client after the client sending retransmissions to the server.

Any idea, what the problem could be?

PS: I'm more than happy to provide you with more Information (ctdb config file, firewall configuration, pcap, whatever ;) ) but this is long enough ....

Comment: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/SMB3_kernel_status states under 'still need to do': witness notification protocol, therefore I assume, a SMB3 fail over is not supported yet.

Comment: https://www.samba.org/~gd/slides/sambaxp-2016.pdf seems like witness protocol is somehow close to be finished? Will test the displayed commands from the PDF.

Comment: I suspect, that there is no open connection to the failover server, the RST package indicates that, the Samba client doesn't try to connect. Is there maybe a way to instruct the client to try a reconnect? (Windows or Linux based)

Comment: https://www.samba.org/~tridge/talks/apac07_ctdb.pdf, page 9 states it was possible with Samba 3.0. I cannot believe they would remove a feature that important in future releases.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, on. But I also did not try this for at least half a year, so I'm certanly not up to date. My last info was, that Samba does not support this (yet?) (Windows 2012 does, but I cannot guarantee that, haven't tried just read about it).